# Visual studio 2012 Outlook plugin how to enter text in search text box

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, outlook-addin

I am developing an Outlook 2013 plugin in Visual Studio.

How can I programmatically insert text in the Outlook search box?

I have a custom button in the ribbon tool bar. I need to have text automatically input into the search box when the user clicks on this button.

This is the search box I mean:

[image: Screenshot of search box]

Answer (score 2):

Use the Explorer.Search method - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869309(v=office.15).aspx